# Performance of jQuery script which dynamically shows/removes images

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, lightbox

I'm thinking about best way to attach an image button to each row of a list. I want every row to have a button. After Click, the script should append a div with image (and run a lightbox).

Do you think optimal way of doing that is:

1. onClick -> append  and hide them
2. Run LightBox
3. onExit -> .remove() images

I'm worried about performance of that. Will it slow browser significantly or rather not?

Fast written code:

```
function test(){
  $.post(url, {id:'1'}, function(data){
    $("#cache").append(data).children("a").first().trigger("click");
    //returns sth like <a href="" rel="lightbox"></a>
  });
}
```

And in lightbox.js at function which closing down script:

```
$("#cache").empty();
```

Comment: How many images, please show example HTML

Comment: I haven't started yet. I'm planning how to do that in most optimum way. For every row can be about 3 pictures (maximum resolution 768x1024), so maximum weight of one pack is about 1MB, but on the screen You can have up to 200 rows...

Comment: Please show an example page so we can judge.

Comment: What performance are you worrying about? The DOM operations done by jQuery will be blazingly fast, you won't notice any delay.

Comment: @Bergi: I mean that if any user will start opening huge number of files, will there stay any superfluous data in browser cache?

Comment: Whether the images (or any data) stay in the browser cache depends on their HTTP cache headers, not on your script that loaded them.